# Abstract vector algebra with scalars

Tags: vector, parametric-functions, tensors

I am interested in expanding a vector expression in terms of the scalar parameter, but it doesn't give the expected result

```
$Assumptions = (ϵ) ∈ Reals;
$Assumptions = (r | k) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals];

A[r_] := Module[{M},
$Assumptions = r ∈ Vectors[3, Reals];
M = r + k*ϵ // Simplify;
Return[M]
];

q[r_] := Module[{M},
$Assumptions = r ∈ Vectors[3, Reals];
M = ϵ*(r\[Cross]A[r]) + ϵ*r // Simplify;
Return[M]
];

q[r]

Coefficient[Expand[TensorReduce[q[r]], ϵ], ϵ, 1]

Coefficient[Expand[TensorReduce[q[r]], ϵ], ϵ, 2]
```

Edit:

Output of the first Coefficient is

```
    r + r\[Cross](r + k ϵ)
```

and should be

```
   r+ r\[Cross]r (* same as just r *)
```

and output of the second Coefficient is

```
   0
```

and should be

```
  r\[Cross]k
```

Comment: "doesn't give the expected result" - what is the expected result?

Comment: You really don't need to use `Module` for these functions, you could rewrite them as `A[r_] := Assuming[r ∈ Vectors[3, Reals],
   r + k*ϵ // Simplify
   ];

q[r_] := Assuming[r ∈ Vectors[3, Reals],
  ϵ*(r\[Cross]A[r]) + ϵ*r // Simplify
  ];`

Comment: same problem with this. The expected result is r for the first Coefficient and r x k for the second one.

Comment: I can't really help on that, just trying to help formulate the question better.  It doesn't really have anything to do with the `Module`, so the title of the question should be changed.  Next, you should edit the question to show what output you do get and what output you expect.

Comment: You need to use `$Assumptions = ϵ∈Reals && (r|k)∈Vectors[3,Reals]` at the top, and remove the redefinitions of `$Assumptions` in your code.

Comment: Comment from @Carl Woll helped but not entirely. If I change the variable, I don't get good results i.e. still have the same problem: `q[rp]` `Coefficient[Expand[TensorReduce[q[rp]], [Epsilon]], [Epsilon], 1]` `Coefficient[Expand[TensorReduce[q[rp]], [Epsilon]], [Epsilon], 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the value of [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$Assumptions), the old value of [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions) is lost. Instead, use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming):

```
WolframLanguageData["Assuming","PlaintextUsage"]
```

> `Assuming[assum, expr]` evaluates `expr` with assum appended to `$Assumptions`, so 
>   that `assum` is included in the default assumptions used by functions such as 
>   `Refine`, `Simplify`, and `Integrate`.

In your case you need to use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming) when you call [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce). So:

```
$Assumptions = ϵ∈Reals && (r|k)∈Vectors[3, Reals];

A[r_] := r + k ϵ

q[r_] := ϵ (r \[Cross] A[r]) + ϵ r

expanded = Assuming[rp ∈ Vectors[3, Reals], Expand @ TensorReduce[q[rp]]]

Coefficient[expanded, ϵ, 1]

Coefficient[expanded, ϵ, 2]
```

> rp ϵ - ϵ^2 k \[Cross] rp
>
> rp
>
> -k \[Cross] rp